# unable to write in a directory by ACL users granted with write permission

Tags: server, permissions, acl

I have two directories

```
/home/user1/htdocs/  
/home/user2/htdocs/
```

I have provided permission to www-data using:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/user1/htdocs/  
chmod -R 755 /home/user1/htdocs/
```

Then used ACL to provide permission to the site user `user1` using:

```
setfacl -m u:usr1:rwx /home/user1/htdocs/  
setfacl -m u:usr1:000 /home/user2/htdocs/
```

The later one works with permission 000 works but the 1st ACL statement does not work as I could not write to htdocs using user1.

Comment: What do you mean by "could not write to htdocs"?

Comment: What does `getfacl /home/user1/htdocs` and `getfacl /home/user2/htdocs` give you?
Alternatively I'ld recommend you archiving what you want using `chown -R user1:www-data /home/user1/htdocs` meaning: user1 gets full access, www-data may still read and execute

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
chown 755 /home/user1/htdocs/
```

You have to run

```
chmod 755 /home/user1/htdocs/
```

Comment: sorry!! that was  typo error..